# cmake can not find boost::signals2

Tags: c++, boost

I have this line in cmake:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework thread system filesystem signals2 REQUIRED)
```

when I run the cmake, it can not find signals2 component. If I try signals, then it worked well.

I am using boost 1.55 and I checked and it has signals2 component.

Any idea why it can not find signals2 component?

Comment: Just remove `signals2` from `find_package`, it's header-only anyway.

Comment: @IgorR. Thanks. So it works without any include file? How o include the *.h path to project?

Comment: @mans: Header-only means it needs headers only. This is in contrast to needing a library.

Comment: @mans the search path is common for all Boost libs. Just `#include` the headers you need, refer to [Signals2 reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/signals2.html) for details.

Comment: Use `include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})` in your `CMakeLists.txt` will resolve the inclusion of `boost::signals2` components in your code (as stated removing `signals2` from your `find_package(...)` has to be done).