# Cmake can't find Boost signals2

Tags: cmake, boost, boost-signals2, signals2

I need the component signals2 of Boost. I wrote these lines in my cmake:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS signals2 REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(APP PUBLIC
    Boost::signals2
)
```

But I got this error:

```
-- Could NOT find XKB (missing: XKB_LIBRARY XKB_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "0.5.0")
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_signals2"
  (requested version 1.74.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_signals2Config.cmake
    boost_signals2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_signals2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_signals2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_signals2" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package)
```

Also I tried to build the cmake with the command: cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/include/boost/signals2 .. But I have the same error.

I read the question: [stackoverflow signals2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252213/cmake-can-not-find-boostsignals2)

So I removed signals2 from find_package:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(APP PUBLIC
    Boost::signals2
)
```

But I have this error:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at /opt/Qt/6.5.3/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:588 (add_executable):
  Target "CartoTools" links to target "Boost::signals2" but the target was
  not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/Qt/6.5.3/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:549 (_qt_internal_create_executable)
  /opt/Qt/6.5.3/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Core/Qt6CoreMacros.cmake:741 (qt6_add_executable)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:54 (qt_add_executable)
```

I am sure that signals2 is in the path: /usr/include/boost/signals2. I installed boost like: sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to get it to compile, these are the steps I followed:
First, I reinstalled the boos library.
Then, I followed this tutorial to install the latest version: [tutorial](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-boost-c-on-ubuntu-20-04-or-22-04/)
Finally I changed my CMake to:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(APP PUBLIC
    Boost::boost
)
```

That's all!